# Laravel Live Search Results Display Issue on the View

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, search

I'm trying to implement a live search in my laravel application.

Following is my index function in the controller (`ParticipantController.php`). Here if there is no search happens, then displaying the participants by default.

```
public function index(Request $request)

    {

        if($request->ajax()){
            
            
            $data = User::orderBy('id','DESC')
            ->WHERE('role_id','=','3')
            ->where('email','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
            ->paginate(12);

            return view('admins.participants.index',compact('data'))

                ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 12 );
        }

        else{

            $data = User::orderBy('id','DESC')->WHERE('role_id','=','3')->paginate(12);

            return view('admins.participants.index',compact('data'))

                ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 12 );

        }
        

    }
```

following is my view (only included the relevant part)

```
<div class="row mt-5 ">

    <div class="col-md-12 mb-2 text-right">
        
        <input type="text" class="form-controller" id="search" name="search"></input>

    </div>    

</div>

<div class="row mt-2 participant-row">
            
            @foreach ($data as $key => $user)

            <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">

                <div class="white-panel  w-100 ">

                    <div class="card p-2 ">
                
                        <div class="row no-gutters ">

                            <div class="col-auto my-auto">

                                @if(empty($user->image_id))
                                <img src="/propics/default-avatar.png" class="img_participant">

                                @else
                                <?php if(file_exists('propics/'.$user->image_id.'')){
                                    echo '<img src="/propics/'.$user->image_id.'" class="img_participant">
                                    ';
                                }else{
                                    echo '<img src="/propics/default-avatar.png" class="img_participant">
                                    ';    
                                }?>

                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="col my-auto">
                                    <div class="card-block px-2">
                                        <div class="text-right">
                                            <a class="btn btn-default btn_icon" href="{{ route('participants.edit',$user->id) }}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>

                                            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['participants.destroy', $user->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}

                                                    {!! Form::button('<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn_icon','type'=>'submit','onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure want to remove this User?")']) !!}

                                            {!! Form::close() !!}
                                        </div>
                                        <hr>    
                                        <h4 class="card-title participant_name alas">{{ $user->first_name }} {{ $user->last_name }}</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text participant_email alas">{{ $user->email }}</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>    
    
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            @endforeach

</div>
```

And set my route as (`web.php`),

```
Route::resource('/admins/participants','Admin\ParticipantController');
```

Following is my Javascript which I included at the bottom of my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#search').on('keyup',function(){
$value=jQuery(this).val();
$.ajax({
type : 'get',
url:"{{ route('participants.index') }}",
data:{'search':$value},
success:function(data){
    jQuery('.participant-row').html(data);
}
});
})
</script>
```

Now the issue is when I search for something, as the result, the current code provides me a whole new view inside the old view. It loads a new view (with the menus and all) inside the target div class whichi mentioned in my javascript code.

Comment: `admins.participants.index` Does this have `@extends('layout')` or something, extending some parent layout?

Comment: yes, it loads the top navi @extends('layouts.admin')

Comment: Exactly, then it won't work.  It just need to return a div, else it will always be  _whole new view inside old view_

Comment: So what would be the fix, where do I need to change?

Comment: When you remove all layout inheritance and just simply return the div, it should work correctly.

Comment: You can keep this piece of div in separate blade file and include it wherever needed.

Comment: But if I remove the @extend, then it would affect to my view design, right?

Comment: So, create a new blade file and add the relevant divs and return that div on ajax search

Comment: in that case, I have another issue, when there is no search by default I'm displaying the users in the same div, so if I try to load that target new from a new blade, will it be affected ?

Comment: That depends on your query results I presume.

Comment: so I have created a different blade called, results.blade.php and included the mentioned html part there and include the results blade inside the index blade, but same results again and again...

Comment: Can you share the updated code?